# Multiplos Spinners em um só

Tags: java, android

> Eu tenho um Spinner A ,gostaria de se eu clicasse em uma opçao do A,abrisse uma opçao no B,Se eu clicasse no segundo item do A ,abrisse um diferene no b,multiplos inputtext em um spinner só

```
    catliv = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.catergorialiv);


    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Categoria");
    list.add("Informática");
    list.add("Didatico");
    list.add("Literatura");
    list.add("Infantil");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    catliv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

> Spinner 2 :

```
    subcatlivro = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.subcatergorialiv);
    subcatlivro.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    List<String> list6 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list6.add("Subcategoria");
    list6.add("Aplicativos");
    list6.add("Banco de dados");
    list6.add("Computação Gráfica");
    list6.add("Engenharia da Computação");
    list6.add("Gerenciamento de Projetos");
    list6.add("Hardware");
    list6.add("Inteligência Artificial");
    list6.add("Internet");
    list6.add("Jogos");
```

Comment: Não entendi nada.

Comment: Cara queria que quando selecionasse "Informática",aparecesse a subcategoria que esta ali,se selecionasse didatico,aparecesse uma outra subcategoria como portugues etc..mas isso tudo no mesmo Spinner..Não sei como fazer isso...

Comment: Mas acha que vai ficar bom assim? Não seria melhor recarregar o segundo spinner apenas com as subcategorias do item selecionado no primeiro?

Comment: De qualquer forma, para recarregar o spinner é só alterar os dados da variável list6 e notificar o adapter do spinner que os dados alteraram, usando um dataAdapter.notifyDataChanged();